# jquery html() is decoding html entities by default?

Tags: jquery, html, html-entities

I dont know why on earth jquery html() is doing this, but after i do

```
$('html').html()
```

i get "&copy" automatically converted to ©

anyway to avoid this? I need to dump the html of the page using javascript and dont need this useless conversions that are screwing up the html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really isn't the jQuery, or even JavaScript for that matter.

The browser will hold its own normalised representation of the underlying DOM. It will bear a close resemblence the the document itself, but character decoding (like the above) will be preserved.

Have a read of the following:

http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/intro/

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/146257-body-innerhtml-issue

I'm afraid there is no way around this as far as I am aware.

Comment: ;( funny that firebug gets it right (e.g. without decoding it)
do u know any other library/function that can dump the html of a page the "right" way?

Comment: Browsers don't keep the original source around. You'd have to use XHR or similar to re-request the page from the server.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should not. check what you really get using in FF firebug.

```
console.log($('html').html());
```

Comment: it shouldnt but it is. checked using log, dumping to file, etc.

Comment: you can file a bug report. http://bugs.jquery.com/, but I guess @James Wiseman has a point here.

Comment: take a look at this post as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162270/dom-exception-when-assigning-html-entities-to-innerhtml