# Escaped html characters are being unescaped by jquery .html() in some browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, cross-browser, html-escape-characters

This is my code:

`console.log($('p').html())`

`<p><span data-htmlContent="&lt;p&gt;This is not really in a p tag.&lt;/p&gt;">.</span>.</p>`

In Chrome and older FireFox the console logs: `<span data-htmlcontent="&lt;p&gt;This is not really in a p tag.&lt;/p&gt;">.</span>.`

But in IE and newer FireFox it logs: `<span data-htmlcontent="<p>This is not really in a p tag.</p>">.</span>.`

Problem can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nzj52/9/

Comment: I'm getting the same result in FF24 and ie10

Comment: very interesting bug...  my first guess is a problem with jQuery's html() selector, but let me play with it and see what I come up with.

Comment: @megawac, how disheartening. It was working in an old version of FF but when I updated, it broke just like you said. I'll edit question.

Comment: The problem isn't regex related at all : the problem is that the &lt; and &gt; are unescaped in the HTML given by the html function (the `oldHtml` string) even while they're in an attribute. This question should be fixed to remove all references to regexes and include the relevant parts.

Comment: Note also that this isn't a jQuery bug, it rather looks like a bug in `innerHTML` accessor.

Comment: @dystroy, very helpful. I was looking in the completely wrong place. I've changed the question to remove the regex part.

Comment: Turns out this was a repeat of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283434/jquery-html-is-decoding-html-entities-by-default

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with how each browsers console operates compared to the rendering operation. If you did and alert instead - would your answer change?

Instead of calling     console.log($('p').html()); 
Try calling            console.log($('p').text());