# How do I convert named HTML entities to numeric HTML entities in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-entities

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162270/dom-exception-when-assigning-html-entities-to-innerhtml) (I have the same problem), how do I convert a string that has entities like `&nbsp;` to a string those entities as `&#160;`, with javascript/jquery ?

Comment: I don't know if there are more in HTML5, but here is a list of entities in HTML4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[php.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/index) can be useful to this:

http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode:424
http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars_decode:427
http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replace(/$#160/g, '&nbsp');
```